# Bootstrap 3 - Customizing the position of navbar relative to brand/logo when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've started to build my first website and I'm trying out the Bootstrap 3 framework.

The navbar I've chosen is setup to respond to the screen size so eventually it collapses into to a little button for use on tablets and mobile.

I don't really like the default position of the collapsed navbar items though; they appear immediately next to the logo when I'd prefer it them to start below the logo. I.e. in the blue dashed area in this screen shot:

[image: ideal navbar location for tables / mobiles]

The narrower the screen width, the more problematic it becomes:

[image]

The navbar collapses at a width of 767px; I've had a poke around the bootstrap css and noticed there are a bunch of `@media` queries, but not sure which is the one that will help me, nor am I sure how to get the navbar items to drop below the logo when its collapsed.

Here's my navigation bit of my html so far (and obviously css / js is being picked up from the bootstrap files).

```html
<header>

    <!-- navigation -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="MyLogo">LOGO HERE</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PAGE 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PAGE 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PAGE 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PAGE 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PAGE 5</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5yeLro2/). You need to post more code or make a jsfiddle with your code since it seems something else is effecting your nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using your code on jfiddle.  Some of your code is off.  Bootstrap, by default is supposed to do what you want it to do - the collapsed should be coming down under the logo.

You just left off the navbar-header div surrounding the buttons and brand.. see below:

```
<header>

<!-- navigation -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">

     <div class="navbar-header"><!-- navbar-header should go here -->

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="MyLogo">LOGO HERE</a>

        </div><!--header should end here -->

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE 5</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```